# Dart http getting: "FormatException: Filter error, bad data" with Microsoft Translator Text API

Tags: flutter, dart, http

This is my code, I'm getting weird exception, I don't know what is wrong. I'm using Microsoft Translator API and trying to send requests with Dart http package, I tried connecting to different endpoint and it worked. Something fails when the program tries to get the response with client.post method.

```
Future<List<String>> microsoftTranslatorDictionaryLookup(
    {required String input, required String from, required String to}) async {
  // Checking if the parameters are correct
  if (from != "pl" && from != "en") {
    throw Exception(
        "'from' parameter inside microsoftTranslatorDictionaryLookup function does not match any supported languages");
  }
  if (to != "pl" && to != "en") {
    throw Exception(
        "'to' parameter inside microsoftTranslatorDictionaryLookup function does not match any supported languages");
  }

  // package:http/retry.dart provides a class RetryClient to wrap an underlying http.Client which transparently retries failing requests.
  // By default, this retries any request whose response has status code 503 Temporary Failure up to three retries.
  // It waits 500ms before the first retry, and increases the delay by 1.5x each time.
  // All of this can be customized using the RetryClient() constructor.
  var client = RetryClient(http.Client());
  // If the request fails, the app won't crash
  try {
    // URL of the http request, the 'to' and 'from' parameters are pased in the URL of the request
    var url = Uri.parse(
        "https://microsoft-translator-text.p.rapidapi.com/Dictionary/Lookup?to=$to&api-version=3.0&from=$from");
    // The response of the API
    var response = await client.post(url,
        // The headers of http request
        headers: {
          "X-Rapidapi-Key":
              "",
          "X-Rapidapi-Host": "microsoft-translator-text.p.rapidapi.com",
          "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        // The body of http request (as JSON)
        body: """[{"Text": "$input"}]""");
    // Decoding the response from JSON, and getting the translations
    var responseDecoded = jsonDecode(response.body)[0]["translations"];

    // result is a list of strings fetched from the response
    List<String> result = [];
    for (var i in responseDecoded) {
      result.add(i["normalizedTarget"]);
    }
    return result;

  } finally {
    // Closing the client
    client.close();
  }
}

void main() async {
  var x = await microsoftTranslatorDictionaryLookup(
      input: "Dzień", from: "pl", to: "en");
  for (var i in x) {
    print(i);
  }
}
```

Excpetion:

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Filter error, bad data
#0      _FilterImpl.processed (dart:io-patch/filter_patch.dart:12:69)
#1      _FilterSink.addSlice (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:505:29)
#2      _FilterSink.add (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:489:5)
#3      _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)
#4      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)
#5      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:10)
#6      CastStreamSubscription._onData (dart:_internal/async_cast.dart:85:11)
#7      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:10)
#8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
#11     _HandleErrorStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:253:10)
#12     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#13     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:10)
#14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#15     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
#16     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
#17     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
#18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
#20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:122:13)
#21     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:405:11)
#22     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
#23     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

Comment: Are you using an outdated Dart version? Some of your code *should* trigger compiler errors in more current versions. In earlier versions, it's runtime errors. Don't know if that's the cause, but if you update and fix the errors the compiler gives you, maybe it helps.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm using Dart 2.17.1, so I don't think this is the problem, what portions of my code should trigger errors?

Comment: `List<String> result;` for example should make your compiler jump. A non-nullable variable, not being initialized. The following `.add` should fail at runtime, but the compiler should have spotted it in Dart 2.12 and above.

Comment: I created a new project and it did show me those errors, but after fixing them it's still throwing the previous exception. I edited the question, updating the code.

Comment: Okay, great. Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. But it's always good to have less errors, even if it wasn't the problem/solution you were looking for :)